# Xamarin Forms Android - Alterar Background da Toolbar

Tags: xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Estou tentando alterar a cor de fundo da Toolbar do Android, em uma aplicação Xamarin Forms.

**Resultado esperado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado Atual:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" 
         parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#b71c1c</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolBarStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyToolBarStyle" 
         parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">#b71c1c</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#b71c1c</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyTitleTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextAppearance">@style/MySubTitleTextAppearance</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTitleTextAppearance"
         parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MySubTitleTextAppearance"
         parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#1976d2</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/MyToolBarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

O que está errado que não consigo identificar?

Comment: Você está fazendo em [tag:xamarin.android], mas a pergunta sugere [tag:xamarin.forms]. Você quer a resposta para _'O que está errado que não consigo identificar?'_ ou para _'como fazer em xamarin.forms'_?

Comment: Não estou fazendo em Xamarin.Android. É um projeto Xamarin Forms Cross Platform.

Comment: O código que você está mostrando na pergunta é do projeto android.

Comment: Isso mesmo. É do projeto Android que está faz parte da Solução Cross. Para ficar mais claro vou alterar a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo específicamente com relação ao código que você postou, a tarja vermelha atrás do título é por causa desse bloco no estilo:

```
<style name="MyTitleTextAppearance"
       parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Simplesmente **remover** esse elemento (e a referência para ele `<item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyTitleTextAppearance</item>`) deve resolver.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fala Diego, funcinou sim. Mas acabei descobrindo que em meu código havia uma linha que setava, no Code Behind a cor da barra. De qualquer forma, estou marcando sua resposta como correta pois dentro do código apresentado ela resolveu a questão. Obrigado.